# UPDATE command based on radio button selection

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

ok so I have a table called voting with 3 columns (idnum, name, numvotes). I created radio buttons in an array based on the number of rows in this table, all with the same name (name="preference") I need to update the numvotes field ( add 1) depending on the radio button selected. Cant seem to get this working with the following code...

```
<?php
$uquery = "update voting set numvotes='". ($_POST['preference'] + 1) ."' where idnum=" .$_POST['idnum'];
$uresults = mysql_query( $uquery);
?>
```

Comment: Does it show any errors? Plus don't use `mysql_*` it is depracated use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead

Comment: @jorgeCampos if i add or die( mysql_error() ) I get this, otherwise no

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in /path/filename.php on line 95

Comment: Could you post `filename.php on line 95` the content of line 95 please.

Comment: @jorgeCampos line 95 is the or die( mysql_error()); code I put in, The previous line is the $uresults one above

Comment: Just to be sure, you took out the `;` before the `or die` like this: `mysql_query( $uquery) or die ("Error in query: " . mysql_error() );`

Comment: @JorgeCamposdid that. Seems I'm messing up somewhere in the WHERE part of the update command. If I take that last bit of code away it updates every field in my database with a value of 1. How would you write the update part so it only updates the radio button that was selected when the button was clicked?

Comment: `echo $uquery;` and see what it prints then you will see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 1 to the value returned for $_POST['preference'], not +1 on the value in the database.  You also are setting the value as a string, not a number due to the single quotes.

Assuming $_POST['preference'] is the current vote count:

```
$uquery = "update voting set numvotes=". ($_POST['preference'] + 1) ." where idnum=".$_POST['idnum'];
```

Comment: Please don't use input variables like $_GET or $_POST directly in your query. Parametrize/escape it, best way is to use prepared statements, to prevent from sql injections.

Comment: @TobiasZander I completely agree, but I was just referencing back to the original code, but I should have placed a warning for sure.